# AndEngine how works the TouchListener

Tags: java, android, andengine

im trying to programming a little game.
So and i have a little D-Pad and i want that the method onSceneTouchEvent run my method while i touch the screen.
But the programm call the method only when im moveing my finger not when im touching the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you only run your method when you start touching the screen.

```
if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     doSomething();
     return true;
}
```